# Using the Heat Equation in moving media

Tags: thermodynamics, models

I am trying to model the heat flow through a rotating disc, whilst the heat is being applied at one point in space.

It is well known that the heat equation comes in this form:
$$ \rho c\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}-\nabla \cdot (k  \nabla T) = -\varepsilon \sigma (T^4-T_c^4)-h(T-T_c)$$

Here I am using Polar Coordiantes so $T(r,\theta,t)$

The term with the $h$ represents the heat loss by the continuum through convection, and the term with the $\sigma$ represents the heat loss by the continuum through radiation.

My question is: how then do I model the heat flow by a rotating disc. Given the heat is applied at a specific coordinate ie $T(R_0,\theta_0,t)=1500K$.Whilst the disc is rotating with some angular frequency

Boundary equations are $T(r,\theta,0)=298K$

I have modified the Heat Equation I have written using the material derivative to accommodate the motion of the disc as such.

$$ \rho c(\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+\dot\theta\frac{\partial T}{\partial \theta})-\nabla \cdot (k  \nabla T) = -\varepsilon \sigma (T^4-T_c^4)-h(T-T_c)$$

Edit: the $\dot \theta$ term came about by expansion of the material derivative.

To model the movement of the disc I replaced $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$with $$\frac{DT}{Dt}=\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+v \nabla T=\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+\dot\theta\frac{\partial T}{\partial \theta}$$

I want to know if  this is correct or if I need to consider anything else. Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: How did that $\dot\theta$ term appear?

Comment: @KyleKanos, by virtue of the material derivitative I simply replaced partialT/partialt with DT/Dt and expanded out DT/Dt

Comment: I confirm that your equation is correct, assuming that the convective and radiative heat transfer is in the z direction and the temperature variations with respect to z are negligible.  Also, the heating cannot take place at a single mathematical point on the surface; it must be over a small but finite area.

Comment: If you dont mind me asking, how would you modify the equation to capture the heating happening over a finite area, via some heat flux. What would be the term or BC that you add. @ChesterMiller

Comment: With the gradients in the thickness direction neglected, it would be a little tricky.  It would be handled as an equivalent heat generation per unit volume occurring over the region of the disk in which the heat flux is being applied.

Comment: If one were to do it without the heat gradient in the z direction. And only as an area. What would that term look like? @ChesterMiller

Comment: It would be a heat generation term in the heat balance equation, equal to q/h, where q is the heat flux over the spot and h is the thickness of the disk.  This generation would apply over the area of the spot.